# undefined is not a function javascript but works with alert box

Tags: javascript, php, function, input

I keep getting this error. I found that by giving an alert box as the first line of the function got rid of the problem. Help :(. I would like the function to loop through the select list onkeypress from a search textbox and compare it with the options in the select list. If it doesn't match it will temporarily remove or disable them. I apologize I may have not phrased the question right at first.
Code:

```
function search()
{

    var searchText = document.getElementById("usersearch").value;
    var usersList = document.getElementById("users");
    usersList.disabled(true);
    for(var i = 1; i<usersList.length; i++)
    {
        alert("test");
    }
}
```

html code:

The problem persists and I have looked all over the internet but this problem I think can be caused for several reasons. I was using opera for testing.

This code creates the select list.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var request = $.ajax({
                        url: "sendmsgprep.php",
                        type: "POST",            
                        dataType: "html"

                    });

                    request.done(function(msg) {
                        $(".users").html(msg);          
                    });

                    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                        //alert( "Request failed online 367: " + textStatus );
                    });
</script>
```

other file 'sendmsgprep.php"

```
<?php
$id = $_COOKIE['id'];
$username = $_COOKIE['username'];

require("connect.html");


echo '<select name="users" id="users" tabindex="4" onfocus="wipe(this)">
<option value="">--SELECT--</option>';

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id!='$id'";

$result = mysql_query($query, $connect)or die("Error on line 31<br>".mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<option value=".$row['user_id'].">".$row['username']."</option>";
}

echo '</select>';
?>
```

Comment: `usersList.desabled(true);` should probably be `usersList.disabled(true);`

Comment: Or `userList.disabled = true`

Comment: changed it still doesn't work. Thank you I made a typo. :)

Comment: @soktinpk I think you meant `usersList.disabled = true`

Comment: What is it supposed to do? What does it not do? Whats the relevant HTML (you're retrieving by elements by their `id`, where are they)? Can you post a [Minimal, Complete, Verified Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces your problem?

Comment: I have tried to rewrite this function about 5 times. I keep getting the error:"boolean is not a function"

Comment: it is supposed to loop through a select list on keypress and search for non-matching strings and temporarily remove or disable them.

Comment: Well, apart from any other problems, `usersList` is a single element, it's `length` will always be `1` (or `null`, potentially).

Comment: The select list is loaded in by ajax.

Comment: the options are retrieved from a database.